# SELECT array comparison in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have the following Postgres table:

```
          Table "my_table"
    Column     |        Type         | 
---------------+---------------------+
 my_char_array | character varying[] |
```

How do I query the row where `my_char_array = {'a','b','c'}`? I tried this:

```
select * from my_table where my_char_array = ARRAY['a','b','c'];
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]

How do I rewrite my query so the types match?

Answer (score 0):

You could cast my_char_array to `TEXT[]`:

```
select * from my_table where my_char_array::TEXT[] = ARRAY['a','b','c'];
```